# .xlsx and .pdf change to .bin when sending a mail

Tags: python, smtp, encode, mime, file-extension

I am trying to send 2 files (an Excel and a PDF) by email but the receiver only get .bin extension.
Here is my working code:

```
from smtplib import SMTP
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

import mimetypes

def get_att_mime(path):
    mimetypes.init()
    mimetype, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(path)
    if mimetype is None:
        print("on a pas trouvé de bon MIME, risque de problème d'extension à l'arrivée du mail !!!")
        mimetype = 'application/octet-stream'
    type_, _, subtype = mimetype.partition('/')
    att_mime = MIMEBase(type_, subtype)
    return att_mime


def create_mime(d):
    mime_multipart = MIMEMultipart()
    mime_multipart['From'] = d["From"]
    mime_multipart['To'] = d["To"]
    mime_multipart['Subject'] = d["Subject"]
    mime_multipart.attach(MIMEText(d["msg"]))
    return mime_multipart


def add_file_list(mime, file_path_list=[]):
    [add_file(mime, file_path) for file_path in file_path_list]

def add_file(mime, file_path):
    attachment = open(file_path, "rb")
    att_mime = get_att_mime(file_path)
    att_mime.set_payload(attachment.read())
    # encode into base64
    encoders.encode_base64(att_mime)
    att_mime.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % file_path)
    mime.attach(att_mime)

"""
def add_file(mime, file_path):
    print(get_attachment_from_path(file_path))
    attachment = open(file_path, "rb")
    p = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    p.set_payload(attachment.read())
    # encode into base64
    encoders.encode_base64(p)
    p.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % file_path)
    mime.attach(p)
"""

def create_smtp_session(d):
    s = SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    # start TLS for security
    s.starttls()
    s.login(d["From"], d["sender_password"])
    return s


def send_mail(d):
    mime = create_mime(d)
    add_file_list(mime, d["filename_list"])
    try:
        s = create_smtp_session(d)
        s.sendmail(d["From"], d["To"], mime.as_string())
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("échec de l'envoi de mail")
        print(d)
        return -1
    s.quit()
    print("envoi de mail réussi")
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = {
        "From": "YOUREMAIL.com",
        "To": "FINALUSEREMAIL.fr",
        "Subject": "Sujet du mail",
        "sender_password": "YOUREMAILPASSWORD",
        "msg": "Bonjour,\n\nTexte du message.\n\nCordialement,",
        "filename_list": ["model.xlsx","model.pdf"]
        }
    state = send_mail(d)
```

If I send simples documents, it works like a charm but when I'm sending an Excel that I have modified (with openpyxl) and a pdf that I created based on this Excel, the receiver get .bin extension instead of .xlsx and .pdf.
I don't know where it is coming from, I suppose it is a Mime problem (decoder/encoder) but I don't get any warnings.

Comment: You probably need to set the correct mime type for the attachment  - see the answer to the linked duplicate.

Comment: The duplicate you showed me solved the problem, it was all about mimetypes :)